# Using factory remote on Astrostart

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, remote-start

I currently have an AstroStart remote start system on my '04 Chevy Silverado. The remote for the AstroStart is a bit bulky. So my question is; Is there a way to start my vehicle using the factory remote. Maybe with a secondary relay that's triggered by a long press on the factory remote. Or something similar.

Comment: Did you try asking Astrostart? I have a DEI remote start but the installer programmed DEI for my factory remote as a dual purpose remote; 1)Lock/Unlock/Trunk Unlock/Horn and 2)pressing Lock twice to remote start.

Comment: I can't seem to find contact information for AstroStart customer service.

Comment: Voxx acquired DEI; https://www.directed.com/news/voxxelectronics-acquires-directed. Try their website for assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give them a try.